# WordCloud a traves de Scraping en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scraping

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código en Python, lo que debe hacer el código es crear un WordCloud a partir de Scrapping de las etiquetas de un perfil de StackOverflow de un usuario que se especifique.

Por ahora el programa hace el scrapping de las etiquetas del perfil del usuario, las cuales se listan y a partir de la cuales se formaran las palabras para el WordCloud, también se listan las etiquetas referentes a la cantidad de veces que se repite una etiqueta, también deberian usarse para el WordCloud. pero actualmente solo esta puesto para que el WordCloud se realice con los nombres de las etiquetas sin tener en cuenta la cantidad de veces que estas se repiten.

¿Cómo hago para "unir" estas 2 listas y así que se tenga en cuenta la cantidad de veces que se repite una etiqueta al momento de generarse el WordCloud? Espero que me puedan ayudar.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#URL del perfil con las etiquetas de SO

url = "https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22851/pablo-lozano?tab=tags"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#etiquetas Scraping
et = soup.find_all('a', class_='post-tag')
frec = soup.find_all('span', class_='item-multiplier-count')

#listaetiqueta
etiquetas = list()
for i in et:
    etiquetas.append(i.text)

frecuencia = list()
for i in frec:
    frecuencia.append(i.text)

#Visualizar las listas etiquetas y numero de etiquetas tengan el mismo tamaño
print(etiquetas)
print(len(etiquetas))
print(frecuencia)
print(len(frecuencia))

text= " ".join(etiquetas)

cloud = WordCloud(background_color="white").generate(text)

plt.imshow(cloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casi lo tienes, solo te faltan dos cosas! Vamos a ir por partes:

### Unir dos listas por indice

Para esto tienes la función de Python `zip()`, esta función crea un iterador a partir de dos iterables que ha unido por indices. Por ejemplo:

```
lista1 = [1,2,3,4]
lista2 = [5,6,7,8]

list(zip(lista1, lista2))
```

**Salida:** `[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]`

*Si quieres saber más sobre `zip()`* puedes ver [la documentación oficial de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

### Crear un wordcloud con las frecuencias

El método `WordCloud.generate()` te crea una nube de palabras contando la frecuencia de las palabras, **pero tu ya tienes las frecuencias por lo que no necesitas este método** el método que necesitas es uno que tenga en cuenta **las frecuencias que tu le pases para cada palabra**, este método es `WordCloud.generate_from_frequencies()`.

Una vez sabido esto, vamos a ver como quedaría modificado tu ejemplo (te dejo la explicación en los comentarios)

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#URL del perfil con las etiquetas de SO

url = "https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22851/pablo-lozano?tab=tags"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#etiquetas Scraping
et = soup.find_all('a', class_='post-tag')
frec = soup.find_all('span', class_='item-multiplier-count')

#listaetiqueta
etiquetas = list()
for i in et:
    etiquetas.append(i.text)

frecuencia = list()
for i in frec:
#Aquí añadimos int() porque el método generate_from_frequencies() necesita enteros no string
    frecuencia.append(int(i.text)) 

#Aquí utilizamos zip para unir las etiquetas con sus repsectivas frecuencias
frecuencias = dict(zip(etiquetas, frecuencia))

#Utilizamos el método .generate_from_frequencies pasandole las frecuencias
cloud = WordCloud(background_color="white").generate_from_frequencies(frecuencias)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(cloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]